# android Root CA and server/user certs

Tags: android, pki

I need own CA for verify own certs in SSL connection.
I am trying this, but does not work:

```
            try {
                AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
                InputStream inStrm = assetManager.open("cacert-devel.der");

                Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStrm);
                inStrm.close();
                intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, x509.getEncoded());
                intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME,"PCA");
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (CertificateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How I can test that CA is installed?
After this SSL to server of this CA,return:

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
            HttpResponse response = null;
            httpget.setURI(new URI("https://url...");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
            int statuscode = status.getStatusCode();
            if (statuscode != 200){
                Log.e("GET", "Status"   + statuscode);
            }else{
                Log.e("GET","Status:"  + statuscode);
            }
```

> IO exceptionjavax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer
>   certificate

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does the certificate get installed? I.e., do you get the install dialog and does it show up in Settings->Security->Trusted credentials->User tab?

Comment: Yes, installed, and tested in chrome on Fedora. Seems that the verifier does not include this cert, or, I am using HttpClient in wrong way.

Comment: What device/version is this? Does the site work with the native Android browser? No special configuration is needed for HttpClient, so it might be some server mis-configuration/unsupported protocol.

Comment: Android browser returns untrusted cert, but web works with continue. Server uses SNI.

Comment: So does the CA certificate show properly in Android's trust store? SNI should be supported from ICS on, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Debug CA has not CN, but problem persists after test CA with CN. 8192bit key, work in Firefox, Chrome and install without problems (asking for a name) in Android browser (DER format). But return as untrusted on https. All parameters of CA can be viewed in trust store (as user CA), cyanogenmod 9.

Comment: OK, unless it is some bug in CyanogenMod, it could be the key size. Can you try with a more common key size like 1024 or 2048? Does your server certificate have an intermediate CA or is it issued directly from the root CA?

Comment: After try 2048 key, self-signed CA problem persist. Server cert is child of Root CA, one level. I can see cert in DER format in /data/misc/keychain/cacerts-added but browser say that is untrusted CA.

Comment: Well that leaves some server miconfiguration or at least incompatibility with Android. Try using openssl to see exactly what the server returns: `openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:443`

Comment: New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression

Comment: Verify return code: 0 (ok)
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.3:443 -CAfile ca-devel.crt

Comment: The interesting part is the certificate chain, right after CONNECTED

Comment: CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = ES, ST = State, L = Loc, O = Org, OU = IServices, CN = DebugCA, mail = info@myldap.com
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.myhost.eud, generationQualifier = 1, mail = root@myhost.eud, x500UniqueIdentifier = 64charstring, UID = 60charstring, emailAddress = root@myhost.eud, C = ES, ST = State, L = lo, street = 2, postalCode = 00000, O = Service, OU = Web, associatedDomain = ca.myldap.com, documentVersion = 1, documentSeries = Serv
verify return:1
---

Comment: Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.myhost.eud/generationQualifier=1/mail=root@myhost.eud/x500UniqueIdentifier=64charstring/UID=60charstring/emailAddress=root@myhost.eud/C=ES/ST=State/L=lo/street=2/postalCode=00000/O=Service/OU=Web/associatedDomain=ca.myldap.com/documentVersion=1/documentSeries=Serv
   i:/C=ES/ST=State/L=Loc/O=Org/OU=IServices/CN=DebugCA/mail=info@myldap.com
 1 s:/C=ES/ST=State/L=Loc/O=Org/OU=IServices/CN=DebugCA/mail=info@myldap.com
   i:/C=ES/ST=State/L=Loc/O=Org/OU=IServices/CN=DebugCA/mail=info@myldap.com

Comment: Looks alright. No ideas other than try a non-wildcard certificate, and maybe get rid of all the UID, OU, ST, etc. cruft.

Comment: Seems that Android does not support "extendedKeyUsage" , and if is critical (as should be) fails. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Ha, this interesting. Do you have details? Consider posting them as an answer.